# I am using elastic trans-coding by AWS for transcoding a video into different versions but I'm not able to achieve the task, Below is my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, transcoding

## transcoder.rb is my file in Model

```
class Transcoder < Gallery
 def initialize(video)
  @gallery = video
 end

 def create
  transcoder = AWS::ElasticTranscoder::Client.new(region: "Asia Pacific (Singapore)")
options = {
  pipeline_id: "id_value",
  input: { 
    key: @gallery.image,
    frame_rate: "auto", 
    resolution: 'auto', 
    aspect_ratio: 'auto', 
    interlaced: 'auto', 
    container: 'auto' 
    },
  outputs: [
    {
      key: "#{@filename}.avi", 
      preset_id: '1351620000001-000040', 
      rotate: "auto", 
      thumbnail_pattern: "{count}#{@filename}"
    }
  ],
  output_key_prefix: "#{@directory}"
}
job = transcoder.create_job(options)
@video.job_id = job.data[:job][:id]
@video.save!
 end
end
```

And I am calling up the create method of Transcoder class in my create method of controller upon the action @gallery.save. Please note that here Gallery is the model which stores all the details about the video being uploaded to aws s3 bucket.

Comment: you've presented the code. What's the problem?

Comment: Hey thanks for taking your time. Actually the problem with the code is that it never transcodes the video and at the same time throws no error. I'm unable to debug the code. Can you please help.